# Sharepoint 2013 online app development

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps, office365-apps

I have been working with SharePoint online for sometime.I have been given the task to build an app to create subsites in SharePoint 2013 online website. I prefer working with C# code. I am looking into SCOM to built the App.I want to know if this can be done or does online version only supports JavaScript COM development.

I have gone through multiple materials from Microsoft but no were its clear about autohosted app running on SharPoint online.

I have created a SharePoint App project and set it to autohost. But it throws token not found error while trying to run it against sharepoint online. Looking for advice.

Edit -  I need to know if SCOM can be used to develop apps for SharePoint online site

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're just starting off with SharePoint apps. SP apps use CSOM (client side object model). I personally prefer JavaScript (JSOM) [MSDN JSOM Basic Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)

If you want to develop against an online environment, then select SharePoint hosted not autohosted. If you are using the app internally then continue, if you are hoping to publish it to the app store then you can report back that this requires full control permission which you are not allowed to request in an app published to the SharePoint store.

Answer (score 0):

When I first started developing SharePoint 2013 online applications I found this article on codeproject a great help.

It might be usefull for you as well: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690015/SharePoint-2013-Online-App-Development-Part-1.

Alternatively you could give the official Microsoft Office 365 training kit a look. It's basically the same as SharePoint 2013 online.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14889